# jQuery $.getJSON not returning data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to my PHP script, via $.getJSON. The problem is, PHP is returning json-encoded data, but my script is not console.logging anything at all.

```
function Club(){
    this.URL = "http://localhost/imp03/includes/ajaxCall.php";
}
Club.prototype.loadData = function(){
    $.getJSON(Club.URL, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

There are no errors in the console, and this is my PHP script.

```
$db = new Database(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$array = $db->getData();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
exit;
```

**This is the method in my Database class, responsible for getting data**

```
public function getData(){
    try{
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inlever3");
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all, $.getJSON need server to return json type data,  json_encode(array) is needed

Comment: if possible, add a jsfiddle you will get more responses.

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to `http://localhost/imp03/includes/ajaxCall.php` in your browser ?

Comment: @TechStone I have edited my code, included the header and I **am** json_encoding my data, still no change.

Comment: @Dave: It is hard to include a jsFiddle, as I can not include PHP.

Holt: I am seeing the JSON data I am asking for. ;)

Comment: first of all, navigate to your url to check the output, may be there will hit error, type echo "'" . json_encode(array) . "'" to check the json data

Answer (score 3):

`Club` is the function, which doesn't have the `URL` property.

```
Club.prototype.loadData = function(){
    $.getJSON(Club.URL, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

should be

```
Club.prototype.loadData = function(){
    // here change Club.URL to this.URL
    $.getJSON(this.URL, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And use it like:

```
var club = new Club();
club.loadData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it, it works as intended:

*You need to use `this.URL` not `Club.URL` on the `$.getJSON()` call*

**test.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['loadData']))
{
    // dummy data
    exit(json_encode(
        array('hello' => 'world')
    ));
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Club(){
    this.URL = "test.php?loadData";
}
Club.prototype.loadData = function(){
    $.getJSON(this.URL, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}

var c = new Club();
c.loadData();

</script>
```

Comment: It wont make any change !!

Comment: @Vimalraj.S what do you mean?

Comment: there might be problem in his URL

Comment: @LatheesanKanes OOps sorry , here he could even use `c.URL`